# SharePoint 2010 not accessible

Tags: iis-7.5, sql, sharepoint, service

My complete SharePoint 2010 site is not accessible. However, the admin site is. The database is still OK. Error: Cannot open database "WSS_Site_Content" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'.

Now, I want to get all the files in the database so I can try to fix the problem and the users can access the documents inside.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or more of your application pools must be running using the 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE' account rather than (as is best practice) a standard domain account.

You'll need to grant 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE' access to the databases affected within SQL server to resolve this.

Instructions for granting the appropriate permissions can be found at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/

Andy